# How to set html string in webview (swift 4.0)

Tags: html, swift, xcode9

I am facing problem, when i am trying to load this type of `html` string

```
(<p>Identify the arrow-marked structures in the images<img alt=\"\" src=\"https:\/\/dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/course_file_meta\/73857742.PNG\" \/><\/p>\r\n)
```

in `webview`.
problem is raised due to backward slaces.

Any Help will Appreciated

Comment: <p>Identify the arrow-marked structures in the images<img alt=\"\" src=\"https:\/\/dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/course_file_meta\/73857742.PNG\" \/><\/p>\r\n

This is actual html string which i have to load on webview

Answer (score 7):

URL string has a problem with forward slash(es) `/` in your html string.

[image]

Correct url string is: https://dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/course_file_meta/73857742.PNG

Here I tried this and its working:

```
class WebKitController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       loadHTMLStringImage()
    }

    func loadHTMLStringImage() -> Void {
        let htmlString = "<p>Identify the arrow-marked structures in the images<img alt=\"\" src=\"https://dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/course_file_meta/73857742.PNG\"></p>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the back-slashes are your problem, you should remove them:

```
let origString = ...
let unescapedString = origString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
webview.loadHTMLString(unescapedString, baseURL:nil)
```